# iPhone Sdk can Access SQL Server Directly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql-server, xml

Is it possible that we access SQL Server 2005/2008 through iPhone app using any Framework, Library etc. I know that SQL Server can be accessed using XML web services & those web services can communicate to an iPhone app. I want to confirm if we can directly access the SQL Server 2005/2008 without using XML Web services

Answer (score 1):

It demonstrably is possible to connect direct from iOS to SQLServer, check out http://www.impathic.com/impathic/index.html

What does not currently seem to exist is a library to assist in implementing this. I'd love for somebody to prove me wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use the FreeTDS library. I have used in the past for some test projects.
The only problem is the license, which might be incompatible with the App store, so creating an app which you want to distribute using the App store, won't be accepted.

If you would like, I can send you a little wrapper I wrote a year or two back.