# Query sql server with iphone (cocoa touch)

Tags: iphone, sql-server, cocoa-touch

I am trying to connect to an sql server 2000 with an iphone app.
I checked the stackoverflow questions but they are old and i couldn't find a proper solution.
I know that i can set up a web service to do it, but i would like to avoid that and i am keeping it as a last resort.
Do you have any clues if there is way (any sdk that i couldn't spot) to connect to an SQL server (to store and retrieve data)?

Comment: Have a look at this question [iPhone Sdk can Access SQL Server Directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910225/iphone-sdk-can-access-sql-server-directly)